# Easiest way to print timestamp to ostream

Tags: c++, timestamp, operator-overloading, ostream

I'd like to add a timestamp to certain outputs to the std::cout / std::cerr ostreams, without using modified standard streams, like so:

```
std::cerr << timestamp << "Warning!\n";
```

or so:

```
std::cerr << timestamp() << "Warning!\n";
```

The output should look like this:

```
[2020-01-23 17:40:15 CET] Warning!
```

But I'm really not happy with what I've come up with:

```
class TimeStamp {};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const TimeStamp &ts) 
{
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    stream << "[" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%F %T %Z") << "] ";
    return stream;
}

TimeStamp ts;

int main()
{
    std::cerr << ts << "Warning!\n";
    std::cerr << ts << "Another warning!\n";
}
```

So I'm basically defining an empty class, using a global declaration and overloading the '<<' operator. This feels wrong. A static function like timestamp() is probably better suited, but I'm not quite sure how to go on about this. All the examples I've found online used the overloaded '<<' operator, but it usually made more sense to do so, because some class state was output. Can I locally create an ostream and return that in the function?

Comment: using a type that is nothing more than a tag to make `operator<<` do something special is not wrong at all. Do you see any disadvantages? Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I agree that this is a pretty clever solution to your problem.  Just mark `ts` constexpr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just looking for a standalone function which is what I understood from a "static function like timestamp()" you can just return the date as a string:

```
std::string timeStamp(){
    std::ostringstream strStream;
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    strStream<< "[" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%F %T %Z") << "] ";
    return strStream.str();
}


int main(){
    std::cout<<timeStamp()<<" Testing!";   
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to include sstream

Comment: That was quick, thank you! Yeah, I guess `std::ostringstream` was what I was really looking for in my question. I used `std::strftime`before, but it takes a C-style string and brought some other problems. Thank you again!

Comment: Kudos for using ostringstream rather than stringstream direclty. Small things, but by choosing the exact type needed, you are expressing the intent of operation more clearly

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with the way you've done it. But if you're looking for alternatives, you could create an `ostream` wrapper:

```
class Logger {
  private:
    std::ostream &stream;

    void print_time() {
        std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
        stream << "[" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%F %T %Z") << "] ";
    }
  public:
    //Maybe also take options for how to log?
    Logger(std::ostream &stream) : stream(stream) { }

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream &operator<<(const T &thing)  {
        print_time();
        return stream << thing;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Logger log(std::cerr);
    log << "Warning!" << std::endl;
    log << "Another warning!" << std::endl;
}
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/YRawuQ

Comment: Very fast, thank you! This is really useful indeed, I didn't know I could create a wrapper so easily. I ended up using a combination of things, I've changed my `TimeStamp` class to a more useful `Message` class with labels and such, so using a `friend ... operator<<` made more sense again. But using a `ostream` wrapper like you suggested is probably the way to go, it seems really handy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) class from the date and time library to represent the timestamp. Then, you need to convert that timestamp to [`std::time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) type and, eventually, convert the date and time information from a given calendar time to a character string according to the format string.

```cpp
auto const now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto now_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_time), "%F %T") << std::endl;
```

**For those who want to know more...**

You can use the [`source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location) class that represents certain information about the source code, such as file names, line numbers, and function names. It is being merged into ISO C++ and is available for use.

**Full code**

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <experimental/source_location>

void error(std::string_view const& message,
           std::ostream& os = std::cout,
           std::experimental::source_location const& location = std::experimental::source_location::current()) {
    auto const now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    os << "[" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_time), "%F %T") << "] "
       << "[ERROR] "
       << location.file_name() << ":"
       << location.line() << " "
       << message << '\n';
}

void info(std::string_view const& message,
          std::ostream& os = std::cout,
          std::experimental::source_location const& location = std::experimental::source_location::current()) {
    auto const now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    os << "[" << std::put_time(std::localtime(&now_time), "%F %T") << "] "
       << "[INFO] "
       << location.file_name() << ":"
       << location.line() << " "
       << message << '\n';
}

int main() {
    error("Some error");
    info("Some info");

    // or

    error("Some error 2", std::cerr);
    info("Some info 2", std::cerr);

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABmAGykADqgWE6rR6hiZmvv6BdDZ2jkYubl6KypiqQQwEzMQEIcam5koqanQZWQQxDs6uHt4Kmdm5YQX15baV8dVeAJSKqAbEyBwA5FLutsiGWADU4u46aUaYs9jiAAwAgqPjk5gzc8gIxHSoy2ubkmO0EwbTszrqRiJ4PqcbW1c7e/f%2BBMSYzEZXudLtdbnM6sRbMAAPoANzwmAA7kD3qDdndMAAPHyuPCLehsAD0Cj6A0w0NYqBYxVoKI2sNQeHQU1cR2IEDq6BAIAhULhCMRUzQtDqUk8U0WCgUzGAmFIZymiqVyqmnO5Pz%2BALFU38ewAIqqCFyUH0CPKNirLWqQFicZD8ZlWNySf1BhSqcwaUK6KLJOLKdSgvrDcbbbiHWxnaS3QHPUFuch%2Bn96BAul0ZgB2WQWpXMAxEb0ighTWioQWzA3Wg5HUvOgCedUwRmhEypAGtuaXEanZtn1sq8wWu9C1Itg1XDsd643m63kB2QEQR3jyQQIF2ur2FUrdXc7jNJJJxABWWSHr7760%2BfPLxYco3c2OsUeYCBi4cvnoHo%2BSY8AMQPY8ABUpEkdM9zmb8TwNUDtxVCCdCg08AEl7D/AB5aCoJzeC5n3WMaQAOioPB2GhWgAVfcC8Mg0CQFgnDlQQqYCKCQjWDaVML1o88GP7S1mMlaVZW4xCwBGY8dFocStzeDM9TOM4GSZKZbBoe9jV5UR%2BSRQtfXFISZTlODLRDdUIX%2BQE/R1BRxwfE183NfjTLMm1sXDLRHSjV1yVYug9IIbU/NoOzQ3c%2B1PMjHlo18j0aQTJNPNTcCsxMwdUACksy1ChNJ1rHkGwIJsWwDBcux7dw%2BwHfMMo/FccpQPLUGnIrZ1K7klxfEd1zLTdKpM3caMQ2DT1A0TXOvAhb1fa0nxfN8/TqxYv1g38AKkYDQOonR9xGmDDxMpVmJG6RUIwrC%2BNM5jguI0jyQou9tt2w96IOxijqGli4rYji7C447eLe5ymM%2BwyROYmTJOkkZ%2BrkhS3g2Wxi0eWx/tSxjWRIBbJAYVAx0x4gttk4G1NQbHcfx4g2SJ2HNkYv4CH6ELVmJ8R5KGHonSGY8hlIUwhlWXnmqGHaZDkVUYoPdxOF5ggQAFjmeg7Y8M0IyQAA5uGPABOY93FWVY/U4VZdaEeXuF5/nBdIYXeYUEBVlIOWFZ6OBYBgRATSMHw7rICgIDQb3fZAYBtfMEjn1ce2ICceXracWwsjreWZdIQOHXQ2hWGThXSCwR5RHYOPefwP40lhTB7dzrFUnzYZraR5Ri6EPAnGIJO9CwFPZftbuehoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkFunHtyAelQHwaSrgBaTkKwkMWZEkZg7ZSNINAgSxGlMTgLG0Co4gSQQ/ACGlT9vyIaSvqo3HPwpUhpUoGn0PJBE/ofWgP9WixDfgAloj8P4tFfh0d%2BPQXRki4JzeWPM%2BbN2FpidWnhV6eG4FMYAyBkBTG1mrKYEBcCEBIFLc%2BUw9BB3YMQGh6ZRZnmkLLYuaZSDK0dlzC2pAjAgGPI7K2Qt5Z2wdk7ThpA3ae1NJNcglBA4%2B0YYITA%2BAiDv1IAPRgLAi6j0RO3Hwfczbc0thg%2BWoxOBTERIQBAUwsE4LwQQohJC1YcJdj0BA/wsBuFTKY/hgjhHoNzrbRQkjnaCy4R2bgkhCIZk4MebgqxuCeG1trDM7h1ba1WMeUx7hzGhPEVIzxpjJCFOtmEyJitSAV2IAEDQ3AgA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: where does the requirement of printing file and line come from?

Comment: i mean it isnt wrong, but your good suggestion to use `<chrono>` is hidden behind stuff that is not obviously related to the quesiton

Comment: you are right... i just wanted to give OP a bit more than he asked and another point of view... I will try to highlight the stuff related to question

Comment: I would recommend to take the stream as parameter for those function (perhaps defaulting to `std::cerr` / `std::cout`). Hardcoded `std::cout` can be a pain in the ass sometimes

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 answer updated. tnx for guidance

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've read about `chrono`,  though I ended up using `ctime` for easier "datetime" handling, but your code shows me that using `chrono` really isn't any more work, and more up-to-date, I assume. I didn't know about `source_location` and even though I didn't specifically ask for it, I'm sure it will come in handy, thank you! The handling via a function that takes a `std::string_view` argument isn't quite what I had in mind, however I can see that this is another sound approach.

Comment: is source_location going to be part of c++20 ?